# Materializecss icons are disappearing from html after using th:text attribute from thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, materialize

I am currently learning web app development with Spring and during that I encountered with annoying problem.

So lets get to the point. I am using materializecss which allows to make a button with icon just by:

```
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="save">Send
    <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
</button>
```

And i am getting a nice button with icon:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKsJn.png)

But as soon as I add a thymeleaf attribute th:text it causes disappearing of the icon.

Thats the code:

```
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="save"
        th:text="#{submit}">Send
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

Do you have any idea what can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

th:text overwrites all children tag.  You have to move the text to it's own tag.  Like this, for example:

```
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="save">
    <span th:text="#{submit}" />
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

Comment: You are right! Now it is working perfectly. Thank you :)